# How to decode in java a json representation of Google appengine Text

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I have two appengine applications and am serving a string representation of a JSONObject from one and picking it up in the other. Every thing works well if I don't include a Text object in the JSON

Here is the specific part of the JSON object causing the trouble:

> ,\"text\":\u003cText: rthBlog 1\r\n\"If you don\u0027t learn from history you are doomed to repeat i...\u003e,

Here is how it looks like in string form:

< Text: rthBlog 1
"If you don't learn from history you are doomed to repeat i...>

Here are the relevant code placing the string in the data store [I am using json.simple]:

> Text item_text = new Text("default text"); //it get filled by text longer than 500 char's
>   JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
>   j.put("text", item_text);
>   j.put("item_links", j_links);
>   item.setProperty("as_json", j.toJSONString());
>   datastore.put(item);

Here is the code retrieving it wrapping it in a JSONArray the array in a JSONobject and producing a String [I am using appengine json]:

> JSONArray search_results = new JSONArray();

```
    for(Entity e: items)
    {
        String j = (String) e.getProperty("as_json");
        JSONObject jo;

        if(j != null)
        {
            System.out.println(TAG + ".searchItems() string as json: " + j);

            jo = new JSONObject();
            jo.put("item", j);
            search_results.add(jo);
        }
    }

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("items", search_results);

    return jo.toJSONString();
```

Here is the code picking it up [I am using appengine json]:

> try 
>           {
>               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
>               JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");

```
        JSONObject array_member = null;

        JSONObject j;

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            array_member = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            System.out.println("array member" + array_member);


            /*Text text = (Text)array_member.get("text"); // 
            System.out.println(text.getValue());*/

            String s_item = array_member.getString("item");

            System.out.println("item in string form: " + s_item);


            j = new JSONObject(s_item); //This is the exception causing line
```

Comment: I you want to deal with JSON in GAE/J this could help: http://bit.ly/13eSDpr

Comment: Thanks xybrek can I import this without maven?

Comment: You can download it here: http://bit.ly/15HBbu3

Comment: xybrek I downloaded and installed. how do I retrieve the same db in another class?Mungo mungo = new Mungo(); 
        DB testDB = mungo.getDB("testDB");
        DBCollection greetings = null; //??????
  DBObject greeting = greetings.findOne("{'username' : 'jack'}"); // Get it

Comment: Oh, you can do something like, DBCollection greetings = testDB.createCollection("Message");

Comment: and btw you can also post to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mungo-appengine

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in control of your serialization and deserialization to and from JSON ...

meaning complex object are represented as simple text or numbers.

Here you are trying to serialize a complex object which is not what it is intended for. Make sure you serialize only the value the object is holding not the entire object.

A nice and very powerfull library enabling to fully take control of the serialization/deserialization process is [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Comment: How do I serialize rich text which is longer than a String?

Comment: Since you answered this question I have received no other answers. I find your answer a tad cryptic. Can you elaborate or remove it please.